# Scala: Json representation of an ArrayBuffer/ArrayList ... how to avoid printing out empty information in the collection?

Tags: java, json, scala

I have an ArrayBuffer in my Scala class (somewhat like a ArrayList if using Java). The following is my code:

```
class MyClass {

  val names: ArrayBuffer[Name] = new ArrayBuffer[Name]
  var phone: String = null;

  def toJsonString(): String = {
    return (new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create()).toJson(this);
  }

  override def toString(): String = {
    return toJsonString();
  }
}
```

Then when I try to print my MyClass object:

```
  var myObj = new MyClass

  val name = new Name()
  name.setFirstName("John")
  name.setLastName("Smith")

  myObj.names.append(name)

  println(myObj.toString())
```

---

Then my output looks like:

```
{"names":{"initialSize":16,"array":[{"firstName":"John","middleName":null,"lastName":"Smith"},null,null,null,null,null,n
ull,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],"size0":1},"phone":null}
```

Is there a way I can make the output JSON like below? Perhaps using a different collection other than ArrayBuffer? Thanks!

```
{"names":[{"firstName":"John","middleName":null,"lastName":"Smith"}],"phone":null}
```

Comment: What if you remove `.serializeNulls()` from your call? It looks to me that your `ArrayBuffer` is being handled a little too literally by GSON and that it serializes all preallocated values in it...

Comment: I need that because I want "phone":null be printed as is now instead of being ignored.

Comment: Do you have to use Gson? Have you tried Jackson?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many good options (e.g. use another serialization library instead of Gson, use an immutable collection etc.), but here's a solution with **minimal code changes**:

Add a custom serializer for ArrayBuffer that converts it to an immutable `Array`, thus getting rid of the empty cells:

```
import com.google.gson._
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import java.lang.reflect.Type

class ArrayBufferSerializer[T : ClassTag] extends JsonSerializer[ArrayBuffer[T]] {
    override def serialize(src: ArrayBuffer[T], typeOfSrc: Type, context: JsonSerializationContext): JsonElement = {
        context.serialize(src.toArray)
    }
}
```

Then register it in the GsonBuilder in `MyClass.toJsonString`:

```
def toJsonString(): String = {
  new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(classOf[ArrayBuffer[Name]], new ArrayBufferSerializer[Name]())
    .serializeNulls()
    .create()
    .toJson(this)
}
```

This produces the result you're looking for:

```
{"names":[{"firstName":"John","middleName":null,"lastName":"Smith"}],"phone":null}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to add the ArrayBufferSerializer class as suggested above, but then I got complains saying ClassTag and JsonSerializer are not found. What additional libs that I should import for ClassTag and JsonSerializer? Thanks!

Comment: No extra _libraries_, just two more _imports_: `import com.google.gson._` and
`import scala.reflect.ClassTag` - added to answer

Comment: Thanks! now it complains Type not found ... what else should I import?

Comment: Sorry - added to answer now, it's `java.lang.reflect.Type` (If you're using any IDE, it should be able to suggest the right import...)

Comment: @TzachZohar i tried your solution but getting `java.lang.ArrayStoreException: com.test.TestBean` at `context.serialize(src.toArray)` any solution for this??

Comment: @PrasadKhode Not sure (not enough info...) - this exception arises when trying to add the wrong type into an Array, so ,maybe try calling `src.toArray[Any]`, or replace `Any` with some type that's the lowest common type for all the values in your array.

Comment: tq @TzachZohar my `TestBean` internally has couple of lists, of type `ArrayBuffer` and I was doing `.registerTypeAdapter(classOf[ArrayBuffer[TestBean]], new ArrayBufferSerializer[TestBean]())` and during serialziation, I was getting that exception, adding `src.toArray[Any]` sloved the problem

Comment: @TzachZohar can you help me out in deserializing the same into a proper Scala object

Comment: @TzachZohar I have posted a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45485716/deserialize-issue-using-gson-scala)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
package yourPackage

import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.libs.json._
import scala.language.postfixOps
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

case class MyUser(names:Array[MyUserData],phone:String)
case class MyUserData(firstName:String,middleName:String,lastName:String)

class test{
      implicit val dataMyUserData = new Writes[MyUserData] {
    def writes(q: MyUserData): JsValue = {
      Json.obj(
        "firstName" -> q.firstName,
        "middleName" -> q.middleName,
        "lastName"->q.lastName
      )
    }
  }
     implicit val datamyUser = new Writes[MyUser] {
    def writes(q: MyUser): JsValue = {
      Json.obj(
        "names" -> q.names,
        "phone" -> q.phone
      )
    }
  }

    //Call this class it will return json string as you want
    def converttoJson(users:Array[MyUser])={
        println(Json.toJson(users).toString)
    }
}
```

call converttoJson method

if you want to know how to add data to this object here it is.

```
 var ar = ArrayBuffer[MyUserData]()
     ar+=MyUserData("John","tt","fb")

 var arr = ArrayBuffer[MyUser]()
     arr+=MyUser(ar.toArray,"12345")

  test.converttoJson(arr)
```