# Scala Object with ArrayBuffer - Deserialize issue using Gson

Tags: scala, apache-spark, gson, deserialization

I have a top level scala class something like below:

**FinalOutput.scala:**

```
class FinalOutput extends Serializable {

  @BeanProperty
  var userId: String = _

  @BeanProperty
  var tenantId: String = _

  @BeanProperty
  @SerializedName("type")
  var dataType: String = _

  @BeanProperty
  var data: FinalData = _

  @BeanProperty
  var userCreatedDate: String = _
}
```

**FinalData.scala :**

```
class FinalData extends Serializable {

  @BeanProperty
  var list1: ArrayBuffer[DataType1] = _

  @BeanProperty
  var list2: ArrayBuffer[DataType2] = _

  @BeanProperty
  var list3: ArrayBuffer[DataType3] = _

  @BeanProperty
  var list4: ArrayBuffer[DataType4] = _

  ....
  ....

  @BeanProperty
  var list15: ArrayBuffer[DataType15] = _

  @BeanProperty
  var userName: String = _
}
```

and all `DataType*` classes extending `BaseBean`

I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35791477/1025328) to serialize Scala object into json string.

**ArrayBufferSerializer.scala**

```
class ArrayBufferSerializer[T: ClassTag] extends JsonSerializer[ArrayBuffer[T]] {
  override def serialize(src: ArrayBuffer[T], typeOfSrc: Type, context: JsonSerializationContext): JsonElement = {
    context.serialize(src.toArray[Any])
  }
}
```

then serializing into string using this:

```
val gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(classOf[ArrayBuffer[FinalData]], new ArrayBufferSerializer[FinalData]()).serializeNulls.create
val data = gson.toJson(row)
```

Now I wanted to do the deserialize the json string to `FinalOutput` object, so I have created `ArrayBufferDeSerializer` something like this

```
class ArrayBufferDeSerializer[T: ClassTag] extends JsonDeserializer[ArrayBuffer[T]] {
  override def deserialize(json: JsonElement, typeOfT: Type, context: JsonDeserializationContext): ArrayBuffer[T] = {
    context.deserialize(json, typeOfT)
  }
}
```

and then calling the below to deserialzie:

```
val gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(classOf[ArrayBuffer[FinalData]], new ArrayBufferSerializer[FinalData]()).serializeNulls.create
gson.fromJson(row, classOf[FinalLevelOneSmsOutput])
```

getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 3, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$29.read(TypeAdapters.java:720)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$29.read(TypeAdapters.java:743)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$29.read(TypeAdapters.java:735)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$29.read(TypeAdapters.java:718)
    at com.google.gson.internal.Streams.parse(Streams.java:48)
    at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:54)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:861)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:926)
    at com.google.gson.Gson$1.deserialize(Gson.java:131)
    at com.cv.util.ArrayBufferDeSerializer.deserialize(ArrayBufferDeSerializer.scala:15)
    at com.cv.util.ArrayBufferDeSerializer.deserialize(ArrayBufferDeSerializer.scala:13)
    at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:58)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Deserializer does nothing but delegate the deserialization back to the `context` with the same arguments (same json and same type), which would cause the context to call the deserializer *again* - which creates the infinite loop and the resulting `StackOverflowError`.

The deserializer has to be improved - since we've *serialized* `ArrayBuffer`s into "simple" arrays, we have to *deserialize* them accordingly. Here's one way to do it:

```
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken

class ArrayBufferDeSerializer[T: ClassTag] extends JsonDeserializer[ArrayBuffer[T]] {
  override def deserialize(json: JsonElement, typeOfT: Type, context: JsonDeserializationContext): ArrayBuffer[T] = {
    // since we've serialized ArrayBuffers by converting them to simple Arrays, we deserialize the
    // input as a simple Array first:
    val array: util.ArrayList[T] = context.deserialize(json, new TypeToken[Array[T]](){}.getType)

    // Then, we convert it back into an ArrayBuffer:
    import collection.JavaConverters._
    ArrayBuffer[T](array.asScala: _*)
  }
}
```